# Embedded table have the same height as cell

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to have the table embedded inside the td to have the same height as the td.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="background:red">
        <table style="background:blue">
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jsfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/ekh6z8w0/

As you can see through the fiddle the embedded table is off by a pixel or two. Is it possible to have the blue inside overlap the slight red border?

Comment: I have a table inside the <td>  because I need to represent two half cells under a cell. Like this... http://imgur.com/AvZQyMv. This gets generated using .net's gridview. As you can see there is a bit of white space which I would like to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the padding from td, should work.

```
td{
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ekh6z8w0/1/)**

CSS:

```
table>td, table>td>table {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}
table table {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hello</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is what you want.